# Should I put my JWT token in the URL for password reset functionality?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm currently doing forgot password functionality for the first time and here's the code so far.

*sends the email for the user that has the URL with the JWT token*

```
router.post('/change-password', verifyAuth, resetPassword);
```

*receives and confirms JWT then changes password*

```
router.post('/change-password/:token/:password', confirmResetPassword);
```

the process I'm currently thinking about is in the email I send the user to

```
http://localhost:3000/change-passowrd?token=TOKEN_VALUE
```

but I'm not sure if this is a smart idea or not? I can also use cookies if it's better, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay to store the JWT token store in the URL for reset password functionality. You have to send this link using Email or any other secure communication service.

I implemented this feature

[https://yourapp.com/home/reset/${token}](https://yourapp.com/home/reset/$%7Btoken%7D)

```
const data = {
  from: "yourcompanymail@outlook.com",
  to: user.email,
  subject: "Please reset your password",
  text: `Hello ${user.name},\n\nI heard that you lost your Teeny password. You can use the following link to reset your password: https://yourapp.com/home/reset/${token}
};

transporter.sendMail(data, function (error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
  }
});
```

Now if the user hits this URL, validate the token and redirect or render the change password page.
But don't send the password through the URL.